# wso2 what is default username and password for pizza shack sample

Tags: wso2, wso2-as

I compiled pizza shack sample application and deployed directly on WSO2 Application Server. But I am not able to get in, as I don't know default username and password for the same. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to login as the default admin, or any user you have created in API Manager. When a user logs in ,it generates a token using the credentials provided. If the token endpoint isn't specified , or if API Manager is not started, then the token generation request may fail, making it appear as a login failure. The README file explains how the sample should be configured.

Comment: HTTPSender Unable to sendViaPost to url[https://100.101.153.254:9443/services/AuthenticationAdmin] from where this ip address coming, this is not my system public ip address, any advice?

Comment: Does this come from API Manager Console?

Comment: Yes it is in wso2 AM console

Comment: Yes it is in WSo2 AM console

Comment: Try specifying your public IP for ServerURL under AuthManager section in api-manager.xml. The default value is <ServerURL>https://${carbon.local.ip}:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/</ServerURL> which resolves to the private IP.

Comment: where is the location of api-manager.xml is that in wso2am or wso2as

Comment: even I changed ServerURL with ip address 192.168.2.1 I am seeing the following ip address bound as per the api manager server startup as follows [2013-11-22 21:18:25,123]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent API Publisher Default Context : http://100.107.140.34:9763/publisher
[2013-11-22 21:18:25,123]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent API Store Default Context : http://100.107.140.34:9763/store when setup server url with <ServerURL>https://192.168.2.1:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/</ServerURL>

Comment: To bind entire API Manager to the public IP, you have to change HostName and MgtHostName elements giving your public IP. <HostName>{publicIP}</HostName> and  <MgtHostName>{publicIP}</MgtHostName>. These are defined in <APIM>/repository/conf/carbon.xml, and are commented by default.

Comment: Thanks a lot this resolved the ip issue, now I am able to use ip address 192.168.2.1, however, I am still not able to login with admin account into pizzashack web application. any advice?

Comment: Does it still give the same exception in APIM Console?

Comment: I don't see any log now in APIM console, but seeing this on AS Console `<Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
            <UsernameToken>
                <Username>yourName@t-online.de</Username>
                <Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">yourPassword</Password>
            </UsernameToken>
        </Security>`

Answer (score 0):

The login you have to use to the Pizza Shack application is the same you use to login to the API Store (as a subscriber) - Prior to deploying the PizzaApp you need to set the right consumer key/consumer secret values in the web app settings and re-compile it.

Please have a look at this tutorial, which we did at the latest WSo2Con, I think it will help.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/e0zf7dd8o6t0nyv/Tutorial-APIMgt-WSo2Con2013.pdf
Isabelle.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the document, I will go thru this